# What is the purpose to show Titanic in Peaky Blinders?

Tags: analysis, peaky-blinders

I was watching *Peaky Blinders* and in one episode John and Arthur went to catch one old guy and lady. Lady was john and Arthur's teacher. On that time they were standing near Titanic. What is the purpose to show Titanic ship?

Comment: Historical reference maybe?

Comment: is this based on true event? i mean that scene

Comment: Do you have any argument that it was done for a particular purpose?

Comment: When you say is this based on a true event, are you asking whether the characters were based on real passengers of the Titanic?

Comment: @Longshanks yes

Comment: Ok - you may want to edit your question to make that clear

Comment: I haven't seen *Peaky Blinders* myself, but are you **sure** that ship was even supposed to be the Titanic?  Did they call it that by name?  I found [this forum post](https://www.encyclopedia-titanica.org/community/threads/frankestein-titanic-in-peaky-blinders-why-do-tv-shows-keep-amalgamating-ships.38228/) calling out a number of technical inaccuracies in the shot of "the ship."  First Post also mentions that this scene allegedly takes place in 1923, but the Titanic sank in 1912.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Sounds like it could be a mistake

From the [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/PeakyBlinders) page on *Peaky Blinders*:

> Artistic License – Ships: Season 3, episode 3 features a brief shot of a Cunard Line ship docked in Liverpool. ***Likely meant to be the RMS Mauritania, the CGI model appears to be the hull and superstructure of the RMS Titanic with the vents, forecastle, and colors of the Mauritania added.***

Answer (score 0):

The boat that can be seen is the Olympic. The Titanic sank in 1912 and Peaky Blinders starts in 1919.

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! Please be aware that this is an English-language site, so answers should only be posted in English. You're saying that the boat is supposed to be the *Olympic*; can you provide any evidence that this is the case?